# Guest to Host Internet Sharing - Virtualbox

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualbox

I connect my 3G dongle inside Virtulbox OS (Windows 7) and using it. Now i need to share that connection outside of Virtualbox on host environment (Windows 8).

How can i do that ?